# How to store IP address in java with database using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am connecting a Java program to a MySQL database, So I need the IP to connect it. Hard coding the IP is obviously a bad idea so I made a config. My only problem is I am not sure what to store the IP as in the variable. I looked around an a lot of places say int, but I don't see how that can be correct because integers don't have decimals. What should I do?

Comment: we have to always use the String for hostname or IP address

Comment: "a lot of places say int": IPs have dots, so it seems impossible to store them as integers. If the source is  reliable,  provide the link

Comment: not sure why it is marked duplicate, the question is related to spring not database

Answer (score 1):

> My only problem is I am not sure what to store the IP as in the
>   variable

IP's/Hostnames are stored in `String` type variable if you are looking for data type.

There are multiple ways to configure your application level configurations. For instance, you can store in application properties file, as environment variable, as command line parameter.

**application.properties**

```
db.url="YOUR_URL"
```

**environment variable**

```
export DB_URL=YOUR_URL
```

**Command Line parameter** (Assuming it's a jar packaging)

```
java -jar -D dbUrl=YOUR_URL yourapp.jar
```

Comment: I think the confusion is in database type for hostname or ip address